React-tostify is not working after installing react-tostify package why
Why react-tostify package is not installing correctly and is not working ?
npm install --save react-toastify

import React from 'react';
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
  
function App(){
  const notify = () => toast("Wow so easy!");

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={notify}>Notify!</button>
      <ToastContainer />
    </div>
  );
}


It seems to work for me: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/weathered-resonance-smw573  Though strangely enough it indeed didn't at first.  I re-created the same sandbox with the same code copied/pasted from above and it worked the second time.
